# Sticky Header isnt working -javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have been working on sticky header where i wanted to code my own javascript code for the header instead of the plugin, for some reason my fiddle isnt seeming to work despite i think it is correct.

```
<script>
var nav = document.querySelector('.sticker');
var top = nav.offsetTop;

function scroll(e) {
if (window.scrollY>=top) {
sticker.classList.add('sticky');
}
else {
sticker.classList.remove('sticky');
}
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', scroll);
</script>

/*css*/
.sticky{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

}

jsfiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/j9rfmq4e/10/

P.S - Newbie so please be easy on the comments

Answer (score 0):

When altering the classList, you've referred to the class name of the element 'sticker' rather than the 'nav' variable declared at the start of your script which is returning an error.

```
sticker.classList.add('sticky');
```

Should be

```
nav.classList.add('sticky');
```

Comment: Changed, but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

You have referenced a different element rather than the target element. Replace your code here:

```
sticker.classList.add('sticky');
```

With:

```
nav.classList.add('sticky');
```

Comment: Changed, but still the same result

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2muz9cLc/

This gives the desired effect for me. Have you re-run your fiddle?

Comment: @Alan yeah but it changes the orientation of the list from inline to vertical list